# Nodejs send to specific user get Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to send message to specific user which connected and logging into server by this sample code, but i get this error:

```
Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

this below code is my sample to test:

```
var socket      = require('socket.io'),
    express     = require('express'),
    app         = express(),
    server      = require('http').createServer(app),
    io          = socket.listen(server),
    port        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    redis       = require("redis"),
    redisClient = redis.createClient();

var io_redis    = require('socket.io-redis');

io.adapter(io_redis({host: 'localhost', port: 6379}));

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('login', function (data) {
            console.log(data.username);
            login(data.username, data.password, function (success, value) {
                if (success) {
                    redisClient.set([data.username, socket.id]);
                    socket.emit('login', {result: true, id: value});
                } else {
                    socket.emit('login', {result: false});
                }
            });
        });

    socket.on('message', function (username) {
                redisClient.get(username, function (err, socketId) {
                    io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('message', 'Hey !!');
                });
            });
});
```

why i get this error: i search and read many pages of this solution but as far as i know my code seemd correct, but i don't know whats problem.

error is for this line of code:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('message', 'Hey !!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. not sure why you didn't provide the line number that failed. you have multiple emits.
2. who says the socket is there when redis get finishes? you must check if exists.

`//when you do set, wait for set to finish before doing emit('login')
//also fixed you set, instead of array, to put key and value
redisClient.set(data.username, socket.id, function (err, done) {
  if (err) {
    //now what?
  } else {
    socket.emit('login', {result: true, id: value});
  }
});`

`//when you do the get, check exists
redisClient.get(username, function (err, socketId) {
  if (io.sockets.connected[socketId]) {
    io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('message', 'Hey !!');
  }
});`

3. you have

   var socket      = require('socket.io'),

and 
     function (socket) {

so you defined socket twice. thats not great.

Comment: i'm sorry sir, your guess is right, my problem is on this line of code: `io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit('message', 'Hey !!');` could you fix my code? thanks

Comment: what you should do, is emit('login') after the redis.set finishes, so you must use a callback from the redis.set for that. in the redis.get output, first check the socket exists: if (io.sockets.connected[socketId]){io.sockets.connected[socketId].emit(....);}

Comment: could you fix this part of your reply on my post? `you must use a callback from the redis.set for that. in the redis.get output` how can i implementing that? Thanks

Comment: you can see an example at: https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis#clientendflush

Comment: edited answer, also the redis.set was wrong. so now you have full example.

Comment: it seem problem resolved, please let me to set more, Thanks sir

Comment: need to use `redisClient.del(data.username);` for delete exists key?

Comment: than mark the answer as correct. as for del, check the url i gave you for NodeRedis. its all there.

Comment: I have another quastion, problem resolved and i can send message via opened tab on `firefox `browser, but it doesn't work on `android` devices, do you know whats problem? i get this message as, user not connected and online, but it is not correct, user is connected

Comment: i'm not sure what you are doing on the andriod app or the firefox web app so I really can't say. its just not enough info. suggest you open a new question with sample code of both clients.